# How to inherit event handlers upon removal of elements using class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the html as follows

```
    <div id="parent_div">
        <div class="child_div">
            <p>clicked button 1</p>
            <button id="button1">button1</button>
        </div>

        <div class="child_div">
            <p>clicked button 2</p>
            <button id="button2">button2</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="remover">remove</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#button1').click(function(event) {
            $(this).prev().css('color','red');
        });

        $('#button2').click(function(event) {
            $(this).prev().css('color','yellow');
        });

        var new_html = '<div class="child_div">\
                            <p>new button 1</p>\
                            <button id="button1">button1</button>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="child_div">\
                            <p>new button 2</p>\
                            <button id="button2">button2</button>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="child_div">\
                            <p>new button 3</p>\
                            <button id="button3">button3</button>\
                        </div>'

        $('#remover').click(function(event) {
            $('#parent_div').children().detach();
            $('#parent_div').append(new_html);
        });
</script>
```

In the above code, when remover button is clicked I want the **parent_div** to go empty but I need to retain the event handlers put on them. Because later, I add different html but having the same ids on which I put events before. When I try to do this with the above code, my events are buried regardless of **detach() or remove() or emtpy()** methods. On the new elements, my click event is not working. Please help me out to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this working code.

```js
   

 $().ready(function(){
       $('#parent_div').on('click', '#button1', function (event) {
            $(this).prev().css('color', 'red');
        });
        $('#parent_div').on('click', '#button2', function (event) {
            $(this).prev().css('color', 'yellow');
        });
        $('#parent_div').on('click', '#button3', function (event) {
            $(this).prev().css('color', 'green');
        });

        var new_html = '<div class="child_div">\
                        <p>new button 1</p>\
                        <button id="button1">button1</button>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="child_div">\
                        <p>new button 2</p>\
                        <button id="button2">button2</button>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="child_div">\
                        <p>new button 3</p>\
                        <button id="button3">button3</button>\
                    </div>'

        $('#remover').click(function (event) {
            $('#parent_div').children().detach();
            $('#parent_div').append(new_html);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div id="parent_div">
    <div class="child_div">
        <p>clicked button 1</p>
        <button id="button1">button1</button>
    </div>

    <div class="child_div">
        <p>clicked button 2</p>
        <button id="button2">button2</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="remover">remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, may I know what was going wrong, why does it work on 'on()' ? but not click() ?

Comment: It attached click event on div id 'parent_div' and check if clicked element id is 'button1'